# Flutter Widgets Accessing Null Provider Object

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm working on my first Flutter application and am having difficulty with my approach to using Provider to manage application state. I've simplified things, but the guts are that I have an AppModel class that contains both a user token that they will then use when making API requests once authenticated, as well as their current 'team' selection.

```
class AppModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  Team _team;
  Team get currentTeam => _team;

  String _userToken;
  String get userToken => _userToken;

  void setUser({String token, Team team}) {
    _userToken = token;
    _team = team;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void exitTeam() {
    _team = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

There are main locations a user can be located. If their userToken is null, they should be brought to the login page. If they have a userToken, but the currentTeam is null, they should be on the team selection screen. If they have a team, they are within a set of pages where they can manage that team starting with the "TeamHomePage" widget. At the top level, I have the following widget build function:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppModel>(
        builder: (context, model, _) => (model?.userToken?.isEmpty ?? true
            ? LoginScreen()
            : (model.currentTeam == null
                ? SelectTeamWidget(userToken: model.userToken)
                : TeamHomeWidget())));
  }
```

Within the TeamHomeWidget there are other pages that are consumers of the AppModel that look at the currentTeam property. Within those, there are options to exit the current team so they can choose a different one. To do this, I'm calling the exitTeam function in the AppModel as so:

```
Provider.of<AppModel>(context, listen: false).exitTeam();
```

This is nearly working as intended. When calling to exitTeam from the TeamHomeWidget, it works. However, when I am on any of the other pages that link off of TeamHomeWidget that are also consumers of AppModel, I am getting crashes relating to the fact that the currentTeam is now null. However, I'm intending that those pages should no longer be rendered, as they should be taken back to the SelectTeamWidget. Is this approach not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your **TeamHomeWidget is also wrapped with a Consumer** and use the currentTeam to do something. This Consumer is also listen the AppModel changes, if this Consumer is triggered **faster** than the your top level Consumer Widget, then your app will be crashed.

To prevent this, assign the value in the top level to the TeamHomeWidget

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppModel>(
        builder: (context, model, _) => (model?.userToken?.isEmpty ?? true
            ? LoginScreen()
            : (model.currentTeam == null
                ? SelectTeamWidget(userToken: model.userToken)
                : TeamHomeWidget(team: model.currentTeam))));
  }
```

Comment: This was very helpful in making me understand what was happening in my app better. Ultimately what I was doing was once I was navigating to other routes, they were replacing the route that had consumer logic completely from the widget tree. I added a navigator within the team context routes so that this widget is always at the top level and that resolved the issue. Cheers!